# Can I use Razor views in Sitecore similar to the way I use xslt-renderings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore

I have been using the sitecore module [RazorForSitecore](http://dotnetminute.blogspot.dk/2011/06/razorforsitecore-module-enable-razor.html) in earlier versions of Sitecore. After the introduction of MVC in the latest version of Sitecore this should no longer be necessary and actually the module is no longer supported. But I am confused about this part of the [Sitecore MVC Developer's Reference Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_mvc_developer_guide-a4.pdf)

> Both ASP.NET WebForms and MVC are supported and can be mixed, although a ***single*** request must be rendered by ***either*** WebForms or MVC.

I am not interested (for now) in using MVC with routing and controllers etc.. I just want to replace my xsl-files with razor-files. One at a time. Over time. But the quote above indicates that this is not possible.

This is however what I could do with RazorForSitecore.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Razor views in the same way as XSLT, and you don't *have* to create models or controllers for them.

When they say WebForms and MVC can be mixed, they mean you can have some pages of your site implemented with WebForms and some with MVC, but **you can't mix WebForms and MVC on the same page**(1). If you want to start moving to MVC you would have to do it to a whole page at a time.  So if a page is made from BrowserLayout.aspx, Content.ascx and Widget.ascx you would need to create .cshtml equivalents of each of these.

Note that you ***can* mix MVC and XSLT on the same page** so if your site uses mainly XSLTs, it might be that you can start off just converting the layout(s) to cshtml.  Once you've done this, you could then convert the XSLTs one at a time.

If you don't care for routing and controllers, you can just create renderings based on the `View rendering` template.  These automatically get the datasource item set for the rendering using `@Html.Sitecore().Field("YourFieldName")` or if you want to access the datasource item you could use `@Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem`.  This technique is equivalent to using xslt renderings or ordinary sublayouts (except that with ordinary sublayouts, you need to write some code to get the datasource).

(1) unless you're loading content dynamically via ajax, or an iframe

Comment: So to clarify. I'm not able to switch a single xslt on my page with a view rendering. Right? (I'm not able to get this to work anyway..) And this means that I actually get more value from the razorForSitecore module in the short run.. However I am able to change a single page layout from aspx to cshtml and then use View renderings on this page. Right? I have this working on a clean sitecore 7.0. But it only works if both the layout and the rendering is cshtml-files.